# Cascade and persist

Tags: jpa

I'm a bit of confused about JPA's Cascade annotation.
For example I have two entities:

```
Company c
Employee e
```

In the database `Employee` references `Company` by a foreign key.

If - without defininf Cascade - I do the following:

```
e.setCompany(c);
c.getEmployeeCollection().add(e);
em.persist(c);
```

both `company` and `employee` will be persisted into the database.

So what is the point of using

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "company")
private Collection<Employee> employeeCollection;
```

annotation in `Company`?

Thanks,
krisy

Comment: The default for "cascade" of OneToMany is NO cascade, so no, if your JPA implementation is abiding by the spec it will NOT cascade persist of the collection element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No operations are cascaded by default in JPA. Hibernate implementation follows the spec regarding cascades, so by default it has no cascade operations. You did not mention what JPA implementation you're using.

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "company")
```

I guess you mean the point of *cascade* attribute(which is to override defaults) because `@OneToMany` is specified to make the association bidirectional in this case.